# how to use different color theme in one css file

Tags: html, css

I'm new in front dev, I hade split the style and color of my pages in two css files, One for padding & marging ... and another for colors.

**color css**

```
:root {
    --backgroundColor-headerAndFooter: #183b75;
    --fontFamily: IranSans;
    --headerAppBar: #19417C;
    --tooltipColor: #eeeeee!important;
    --footerLinkColor : white;
    --footerQuotesColor: yellow;
}
.default-theme {
    --backgroundColor-headerAndFooter: #183b75;
    --fontFamily: IranSans;
    --headerAppBar: #19417C;
    --tooltipColor: #eeeeee!important;
    --footerLinkColor : white;
    --footerQuotesColor1: yellow;
}
.footer-quotesColor {
    color: var(--footerQuotesColor1)
}
```

let me put it this way, I want to use different function like `default-theme` or `Dark-theme` for `footer-quotesColor` and I use react-js for my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preprocessors like Sass or LESS to switch color themes. I am showing you an example with Sass(SCSS).

- First, we need to define the colors at the top.

```css
$default-bg: #eee;
$default-primary: #333;
$default-secondary: #199cff;

$dark-bg: #333;
$dark-primary: #eee;
$dark-secondary: #199cff;
```

- Then, we can create another set of variables, and assign them the values as per requirement. So, if we need a light/default scheme, assign the `$default-*` values to the new variables.

```css
$bg: $default-bg;
$primary: $default-primary;
$secondary: $default-secondary;
```

- Or if you want a dark scheme, assign the `$dark-*` values.

```css
$bg: $dark-bg;
$primary: $dark-primary;
$secondary: $dark-secondary;
```